# Getting Absolute Path Of a File From Browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs

say that you have a NodeJS server and a ReactJS frontend that both runs in your local machine only. ReactJS and NodeJS communicates through socketio module. In React side you have a file selecting field looks like following.

```
  <div>
    Select a file: <input id="fileSelector" type="file" name="myFile"><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
```

You want to select a file from the browser and after that NodeJS will process some operations on that file. But in the given code block, input field only stores the name of the file and not the absolute path to it, because browser do not have access to file system. Because of that I can  not tell the NodeJS where the file is so that it can operate on it. What is the best of the bests approach in order to solve this. I do not want to do a trick but make it in the most suitable way. Thanks

Comment: You cannot get the full path to a file, as a browser security restriction prevents that. You can find more about it here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68474

Comment: Thank you for response, I got your point, but is there any other way to pass that file to NodeJS without using full path?

Comment: you mention *local machine*, so you could provide the client side code with a list of files and directories on the local machine to select for "processing", rather than uploading something you already have :/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you for your answer, but I don't think that solves the problem. The selected file will be imported from another computer to a path that I do not know during run time (user decides where to put new file). So the path is always unknown hence can not be pre-added in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this in a browser is for the client to submit the file. Your node server will then perform whatever processing you plan to do with the uploaded file, then you can provide a link for the user to download the new file from your server. This is how most sites handle this.

In node you can use the formidable module to handle files uploaded to your server.

Another option is to build a desktop application. You can use electron to build a client side app in node with access to the file system and you can still use your client code using React.